# Adding text values to dynamically create text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a dynamic form. I have the clone and masking down along with it submits and post to my database but now I am trying to take the value from the previous id #endtime_* and make it the value of the new dynamically created input field of #starttime_*. The ids start with 1. For Example: the first row is:  then next is 2 and so on.

As a bonus maybe someone could also tell me how to make each created row alternate in color. odd rows blue and even rows white say.

Thanks so much in advance!

Here is the code thus far.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function maskInput(){
            $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
            $(".time").mask("99:99 aa");

            $("input").blur(function() {
            $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());
        }).dblclick(function() {
            $(this).unmask();
        });
        }
        var clone;
        function cloneRow(){
            var rows=document.getElementById('TimeCard').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var index=rows.length-1;
            clone=rows[index-0].cloneNode(true);
            var inputs=clone.getElementsByTagName('input'), inp, i=0,n ;
            while(inp=inputs[i++]){
                inp.name=inp.name.replace(/\d/g,'')+(index+1);
            }
            var select=clone.getElementsByTagName('select'), sel, i=0,n ;
            while(sel=select[i++]){
                sel.name=sel.name.replace(/\d/g,'')+(index+1);
            }
        maskInput();
        }
        function addRow(){
            var tbo=document.getElementById('TimeCard').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            tbo.appendChild(clone);
            cloneRow();
        }
        function checkDOM(){
            var rows=document.getElementById('TimeCard').getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
                alert(rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].name);
            }
        }
        onload=cloneRow;
        </script>
```

Comment: post your html as well it will be helpful for people to help you out

Comment: How about providing the markup you are using to clone from?

Comment: So here is everything and I tried to put @RGB suggestion in and it sort of works on the changing the color of the row but it only changes it once, every row after stays as the odd background color.

Comment: that might be because of your "cloning" process, try this `index%2 ? $(clone).addClass("odd") : $(clone).removeClass("odd");`

Comment: `clone=rows[index-0].cloneNode(true);` i cant imagine `index-0` is worth much to this code haha

Answer (score 0):

when youre creating your new inputs in cloneRow, after they're in the dom you can just take your names/index and work them then.

```
$('#starttime_'+index).attr('value',$('#endtime_'+index-1).attr('value'));
```

for your rows, you need to just give everyother one a different/extra class and then style it accordingly

```
.odd { background-color:#cfcfcf; }
```

then, in your cloneRow()

```
clone=rows[index-0].cloneNode(true);
if (index%2) $(clone).addClass("odd");  //added this line
var inputs=clone.getElementsByTagName('input'), inp, i=0,n ;
```

Comment: Thank you RGB for the response. Sorry for the dumb question but where do I put these in the current code?

Comment: I mean your first example. I got the second... :)

Comment: i think right before you call maskInput() in cloneRow() would be appropriate..you need index to have its value when calling it.  also, depending on how you use it, you might want to use input+1 and input respectively..

Comment: and don't forget to accept.. http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png :)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what you really want when you provided no HTML code, but I built something that should at least point you to the correct direction. I made it into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf7n6/) but I'll post it here as well. So assuming your HTML is something like this:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input class="endtime" id="endtime_123" type="text" value="endtime_123"/>
</div>
```

Then this JavaScript will create you new inputs whose starttime equals the endtime of the other input:

```
$(function() {
    $('#inputs .endtime').each(function(index) {
        var endtime = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);
        $('#inputs').append("<input class='starttime' id='starttime_'"+endtime+"' value='starttime_"+endtime+"'/>");
    });
});
```